# Setting state in useEffect then accessing it's properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, use-effect

I am trying to access a property in my state that was set using the useEffect hook in React but I keep getting this error Uncaught **"TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"**.
This is my code:-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Geocode = (props) => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://eu1.locationiq.com/v1/search.php?key=MY_KEY=${props.address}&format=json&limit=1`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setLocation((location) => ({ ...location, data }));
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [props.address]);

  const latitude = location.data[0].lat;
  const longitude = location.data[0].lon;

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Location</h2>
      {location && (
        <p>
          Lat: {latitude}, Lon: {longitude}
        </p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Geocode;
```

The output from the following API call is:-

```
[{…}]
0:
boundingbox: (4) ["-1.444471", "-1.163332", "36.6509378", "37.1038871"]
class: "place"
display_name: "Nairobi, Kenya"
icon: "https://locationiq.org/static/images/mapicons/poi_place_city.p.20.png"
importance: 0.73502675943376
lat: "-1.2832533"
licence: "https://locationiq.com/attribution"
lon: "36.8172449"
osm_id: "9185096"
osm_type: "relation"
place_id: "237011109"
type: "city"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` executes after the component is rendered in the dom. Hence when the initial loading the component takes place, it gets the `location` default value as `[]`. Hence when it access the `data` attribute, it gets undefined and throws error.  Best way to solve this would be to check is the `location` has `data` property or not. You can do it in two ways :

**1. Optional Chaining**

```
  const latitude = location?.data?.[0]?.lat;
  const longitude = location?.data?.[0]?.lon;
```

You can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining.

**2. Conditional check**

```
 const latitude = location.data && location.data.length > 0 ?location.data.[0].lat: 0;
 const longitude = location.data && location.data.length > 0 ? location.data.[0].lon : 0;
```

Also I would advice to assign the default value to `location` as empty object `{}` as you are assigning an object to it rather than an array. It will make the code less error prone.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
  const latitude = location.data[0].lat;
```

is throwing the error, as before the `useEffect` has had a chance to fetch and populate the data, you are trying to access it.

You are guarding against that error in your JSX with `{location && (...)}`, so instead of defining latitude and longitude outside, just put the calculations in there.

Also, you should standardise the types of your `location` state? When you first define it you set the default to a list `[]`, but then when you update it you create an object `{}`.

Comment: I appreciate the help, thank you. Thanks for pointing out the error on different data types